# Suppose |B| = m and |C| = n. Compute the number of subsets of B × C.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I understand that the amount of subsets is 2<sup>m</sup> for set B and 2<sup>n</sup> for set C but I'm not sure what I do next. Is the answer just 2<sup>m</sup>x 2<sup>n</sup> ?

Comment: Yes...but I'm afraid you don't really know why, so: what exactly is your doubt?

Comment: @DonAntonio no, it is incorrect.  It will be $2^{m\times n}$ not $2^{m+n}=2^m\times 2^n$

Comment: You started at the wrong end. First, what is $|B\times C|$?

Comment: @JMoravitz Indeed so...and that's what I read: $\;2^{nm}\;$ . Maybe it was changed, maybe I misread (most probably the last one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the following two facts:

[The rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product): $|B\times C| = |B|\times |C|$

The size of the power set: $|2^A|=2^{|A|}$, or as you may see power set notated instead $|\mathcal{P}(A)|=2^{|A|}$

Use these two facts together and you'll see that the number of subsets of $B\times C$ is:

$$|2^{B\times C}|=2^{|B\times C|}=2^{|B|\times |C|}=2^{mn}$$

Note that $\mathcal{P}(B\times C)$ is different than $\mathcal{P}(B)\times \mathcal{P}(C)$

Comment: Okay, I see now where my error was. Thanks for the explanation, It makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: @MagitrixAlyxra As an aside, the notation $2^A$ to be in reference to the powerset is helpful for remembering this, and the decision to use this notation is in no small way influenced by the resulting identity.  Very similarly another notation you should be familiar with is $Y^X$ denoting the set of functions from $X$ to $Y$ which leads to the nice identity $|Y^X|=|Y|^{|X|}$, the power set being just a special case of this.